# Firebug not showing stack trace for errors?

Tags: javascript, firefox, error-handling, firebug, gecko

I have noticed that even with "show stack trace with errors" enabled from the drop down, only errors that *occur* seem to have traces, but when I do: `throw new Error('foo');` I do not see any stack trace for it even though it seems to appear in the console exactly the same way as other errors that occur such as `iDoNotExist()`.

Is there something I am missing?

It also seems that I get the stack trace for calling `console.error('foo');`. Odd.

It should be noted that stack traces do occur on Webkit Inspector and Opera when doing `throw new Error('foo');`.

Comment: Might help to add which version of Firebug and which browser version you running into this with.

Comment: Firefox 4, 5, 6 and latest Firebug 1.7. Maybe I could try the latest beta 1.7.1bx.

Comment: @rFactor, On Console Just Check 'Show Stack Trace With Errors'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code in Firebug 1.7.1b2 (FF: 4.0.1, on win7) and it shows me stack trace:

```
function a(){
    throw new Error('s');
};

function b(){
    a()
}

b();
```

Comment: It does not give me any stack trace.

Answer (score 20):

For others landing here :

The issue for me was `showStackTrace` is set to false by default for Firebug.

Here's how to enable it :

1. Goto `about:config` in Firefox
2. Change the value of the preference  `extensions.firebug.showStackTrace` from `false` to `true` (Double-click toggles the value).

Comment: The question mentions that the option *Show Stack Trace with Errors* is already enabled, which toggles exactly that preference. So this answer does not solve the initial problem. I guess this was a bug in an earlier version of Firebug.

Comment: The answer may not solve the initial problem, but it sure solved my problem. +1

Comment: I would like to gratulate to the firebug developers for this nice config change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var err = new Error();  
err.name = 'My custom error';
err.message = 'foo';  
throw(err);
```

Or even (doesn't always work):

```
throw 'foo';
throw('foo');
```

Comment: No stack trace there. Tried even on Aurora and Firebug 1.8 with no difference.